# react css root div full browser height

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I can't seem to get the react root div to fill the browser page. [image: The root div only takes up what it needs]

I've tried adding the following CSS, and just about every combination of

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.fill-height {
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto !important; /* cross-browser */
    height: 100%; /* cross-browser */
}

#root > [data-reactroot] { height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by setting `height` to `100%` or `100vh` of `#root` instead of `#root > [data-reactroot]`. This does depend on the rendered structure of your application. You may also need to set the `height` on multiple elements depending on how nested things are:

```
#root {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h2gaxj) showing the functionality in action. You may need to fork it and update it to match more with the structure of your application, but it may be the only issue is you are targetting a child of `#root` instead of just `#root`.

Hopefully that helps!