# html full background color in Chrome(smartphone app)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Recently, I am developing my page via React, but I have a problem with some phones that don't show full-colored background in Body part. 
I have a structure as follows:

```
function App() {
 const styles = { container: { backgroundColor: "#333333", height: "100vh" } };
  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <Body/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function Body() {
  return (
    <div id="body-set" >
      <div className="container">
        <div id="head-slider" className="transistion">
          <p className="head-desc">....1....</p>
          <p className="head-cont">
            ....long contents....
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="programmer-img-holder">
        <img src={programmer} alt="programmer"/>
      </div>

      <div className="container">
        <div id="head-slider" className="transistion">
          <img className="skill-img" src={skill} alt="skill"/>
          <p className="head-desc">....2....</p>
          <p className="head-cont">
            ....long contents....
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Here are related-CSS codes:

```
html,body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

#head-slider {
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  #head-slider {
    padding: 3.5rem 0;
  }
}

#head-slider p.head-desc {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Sarabun',
  sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  #head-slider p.head-desc {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    font-size: 3.3rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Sarabun',
    sans-serif;
  }
}


#head-slider p.head-cont {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'Sarabun',
  sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  #head-slider p.head-cont {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'Sarabun',
    sans-serif;
  }
}
```

When I check my page via "developer tool" in Chrome, at some phones(Iphone 6/7/8 Plus, Pixel 2 and so on), the Body's background is not fully filled (Body's bottom part is not filled - no background color.). Also, Chrome in my Samsung Note9 phone doesn't show full-colored background.(Same in Samsung Internet app :/)

I already tried with many answers in Stackoverflow, but still cannot know how to handle this problem.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

// problem screenshot added.
Iphone 6,7,8:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4ze0.png)

Pixel 2xl:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvYlF.png)

Comment: Please put here code for the part responsible for the background rendering with css you're using, it is not possible to provide any help from what you provided so far

Comment: Hi, I put my codes!. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by setting height to `100%` or `100vh` of `#root` instead of `#root > [data-reactroot]` :

```
#root {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

in reference to this [react css root div full browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349245/react-css-root-div-full-browser-height)

Comment: Hi! I tried it, but it still has the same problem. If I add height:100vh in that container, then it doesn't have the problem with phones but has the problem with Ipads...

Comment: Ok, can you share us the css you're using please ?

Comment: I only used it for the background color.

const styles = {
    container: {
      backgroundColor: "#333333",
      height:"100vh"
    },
  };
  return (
    <div style={styles.container}> ... </div>);

Comment: My CSS codes are full of basic things like padding, font, and alignment. So, I removed all paddings, but the same problem is still shown in some phones. Should I cover/fill the screen using padding? :/ How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Can you share more codes on your post ? Maybe you have an interaction with an other page or css custom.

Comment: I only modified parts that you updated, but it still has same problem unfortunately. Is it related to paddings?

Comment: Maybe. Do you have a screenshot please ?

Comment: I added screenshots.

Comment: Thanks. Can you open your console (Dev tools) and select the white part and give us a picture please of the console please ? Sorry I'm asking a lot but I'm trying my best to help you lol.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your interest and help. I think I found a solution. My problem is related to this one. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349245/react-css-root-div-full-browser-height

Thank you again.

Comment: @ghisooo I'm happy for you. I updated my answer with your explanations. If it's work, you can close this ticket :)